# Поиск окна по процессу

Tags: delphi

Я знаю название процесса. Как по его названию можно получить хендл главного окна этого процесса?

Answer (score 3):

Можно

1. пронумеровать все окна с помощью `EnumWindows`,
2. для каждого окна определить `id` с помощью `GetWindowThreadProcessId`,
3. пронумеровать процессы с помощью вызова `NtQuerySystemInformation`,
4. найти по имени процесса его `id`, а по `id` - хэндл главного окна.